# How to get the spring management server port programmatically?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

In my case I want to use a random port for the `management.server.port` therefore we have to put the value as `0`. after applying a random number from the spring and after running the server with a random number, i want get the number that the management server was started. I tried `ManagementServerProperties` class. but it also give me the value that I put in the property file. it is `0`. but i want to get the real number that the management server running on.